# Division by zero error?

Tags: php

If I get a division by zero, how can I catch it and just echo an error or something of that nature?

Here's the line of code in question:

```
$percent = round(100.0*($row['p2']/$row['p1']-1));
```

Comment: well division by zero is infinite so you must check its not zero

Comment: `if ($row['p1'] == 0)` seems sensible to me...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Division by zero in PHP returns `false` and displays a warning message. You can squelch the warning message by appending `@` to the expression in question.

```
$foo = @(10 / 0);

if ($foo === false) {
   // Division by zero
}
```

It would be cleaner to just try to avoid dividing by zero in the first place though.

Suppressing warning messages is usually a sign that you should be doing something differently. For instance, simply check if the integer is 0 before using it for division.

Comment: pretty bad method ... why not check that weather divisor is  zero or not

Comment: @NullPoiиteя: I answered the question and advised the OP to use a better method. Why on earth down vote that?

Comment: i didnt down vote ...

Comment: Why not make it apparent by doing `if ($var == 0)` instead of suppressing warning?

Comment: IMO error suppression operator is for experts only. It's bad to abuse it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch TRUE ..new bie abuse it and use it like magic error removing thing

Comment: IMHO - Do not use the error suppression operator at all. Errors are there for a reason.

Comment: @EdHeal: Why have a warning suppression mechanism if there are no warnings worth suppressing?

Comment: @Codemonkey there are plenty of thing PHP has but we do not use ... and its php so useless function and operator can exist :)

Comment: @Codemonkey - It is there for the lazy.

Comment: *Don't suppress errors, fix them!*

Comment: @AmalMurali: It's not like I'm recommending it in my answer. I'm simply answering what the OP asked, then recommending **not** doing it :)

Comment: Thanks @Codemonkey - large excel sheets are being imported & compared so sometimes dividing by zero may occur if the numbers are the same (Comparing data between two months.)

Answer (score 1):

Just check that `$row['p1']` is not zero.

If it is zero do something else (e.g. report an error)

Answer (score -2):

If value of $row['p1'] is 0, then you will get division by zero error. If you want to catch it without showing ugly Exception in the UI, you can write like this.

```
try {
    $percent = round(100.0*($row['p2']/$row['p1']-1));
} catch() {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

You will get the exact error message now. And better to use the condition if(0 !== $row['p1']).

Comment: neither i see any need of try cache .. so bad(*) method too

Comment: division by zero doesn't throw exception. http://ideone.com/HHkkEq